# How to connect Profile Controller with User Controller?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I have USER through Devise and have created Profile through scaffolding, now everything is working fine but I am not able to "connect" the user with the profile.

This is what I have done so far -

user.rb

```
has_one :profile
```

profile.rb

```
belongs_to :user
```

I have created the user_id column through migration in profiles table too.

Now when I am logged in and fill the form /profiles/new, it creates the profile but it is NO way linked to the user as the user_id filed is NULL. Also the user is able to create multiple profiles where as I thought he can only create one as I have put :has_one relationship ?

Any Help ?

Edit - in profiles_controller file, I also tried to change

```
@user_profile = UserProfile.new(params[:user_profile])
```

to

```
@user_profile = current_user.userprofile.new(params[:user_profile])
```

but it is giving undefined method 'UserProfile'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
@user_profile = current_user.userprofile.new(params[:user_profile])
```

Should be

```
@user_profile = current_user.build_user_profile(params[:user_profile])
```

Comment: I think it should be `@user_profile = current_user.build_profile(params[:user_profile])` (see http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#has_one-association-reference)

Comment: I am still getting the same error - undefined method `build_profile'

Comment: Aah, got it, the code is fine, @user_profile = current_user.build_user_profile(params[:user_profile]), can you please tell me what was wrong with CREATE as I have used it before and it worked fine.

Comment: If you create the UserProfile on its own it will not have a `user_id`. Building the association on the `current_user` sets the `user_id` properly. It's that simple.

Comment: It appears your profile model is called UserProfile so I've rolled back Baldrick's answer edit.

Comment: Johnny, can you tell me how can I link to current users profile ? there is users table and there is user_profiles table with user_id as foreign key. I am trying to use '<%= link_to 'Profile', user_profile %>' in application.html.erb but that is not working